# How to customize Python domain in Sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I’d like to customize the Sphinx Python domain to recognize a custom field within a docstring for a method and generate custom HTML for it.

For example, let’s say I want to add a category for each method in a module. I want to be able to write a doc string like this:

```py
def func():
    “””
    Does something

    :category: A/B/C
    “””
    …
```

and then have custom HTML display on the generated autodoc.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is, but it will require code (a custom extension) and might not be easy.

There might be a simpler way, but by subclassing [`PyClassLike`](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/b4276edd848d112b4e981011c334d27cbcb20018/sphinx/domains/python.py#L740), probably changing the values of [`doc_field_types`](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/b4276edd848d112b4e981011c334d27cbcb20018/sphinx/domains/python.py#L432) and registering this with [`app.add_directive_to_domain("py", "class", YourClass, override=True)`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/extdev/appapi.html#sphinx.application.Sphinx.add_directive_to_domain) in a [`setup(app)`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html?highlight=setup#confval-extensions?highlight=setup) fonction in your [`conf.py`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.htm), you might get what you want.